# ¿Cómo podría validar un evento dentro de un formulario en vb.net si ocurre otro evento en otro formulario?

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, datagridview

Trataré de ser lo más breve posible y que sea entendible:

Tengo dos formularios: "A" y "B". Mi formulario "A" es el principal, contiene una grilla.
Mi formulario "B" lo utilizo para buscar los productos a ser cargados en la grilla del formulario "A".

Pero utilizo el formulario de búsqueda solo en determinados casos.
Por ejemplo: Si el usuario ingresa en la celda del código el código tal cuál se encuentra en la BD, entonces se llena la fila sin necesidad de abrir el formulario de búsqueda ("B").
De lo contrario, si ingresó parte del código (coincidencias), realizo la consulta en la BD y se abre el formulario "B" con la cantidad de registros coincidentes encontrados. Estos registros se cargan también dentro de una grilla que está en el form "B".
Hasta aquí, todo bien. Lo que ocurre es que si el usuario ingresa el código tal cuál se encuentra en la BD, entonces se hacen algunas validaciones dentro de la grilla del form "A" (para que no se quede vacía, para controlar que si no existe el código no pase a otra celda, para que no vaya agregando filas si no se cargó la fila anterior, etc).
¿Cuál es el problema si el usuario ingresa el código y se abre el form "B" con los resultados coincidentes?
Que si el usuario cierra el form "B" sin seleccionar un registro (Hay un evento que al hacer doble click realiza un procedimiento y envía la fila seleccionada a la grilla del form "A"), se salta todas las validaciones que he hecho en el form "A" **y lo que necesito validar es que desde mi form "A" yo pueda saber si el usuario hizo doble click sobre una de las celdas del form "B" o si lo cerró sin seleccionar nada.** Entonces, si no seleccionó nada, lo que haré es bloquearle la salida de la celda hasta que borre lo que escribió o hasta que seleccione un producto de la grilla del form "B".

Espero haber sido claro y si de repente encuentran alguna solución más práctica al planteamiento expuesto, les agradecería bastante si me pudieran iluminar. Ya estoy bloqueado porque estoy atascado en esta parte de mi desarrollo desde la semana pasada.

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El evento closing del formulario B no te sirve para nada?

Comment: El evento Closing sólo me permite invocarlo en el Form "B", pero no es visible desde el Form "A". Lo que necesito es validar desde el Form "A". Igual, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: y que B levante un evento que tome A al cerrarse... sabes hacer eso?

Comment: Realmente no sé cómo hacerlo. Es decir, nunca lo hice. Se me ocurren formas pero si podes darme sugerencias, trataré de hacerlo y realizar las pruebas.